# Ranks and identification of elements in r

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit, kolmogorov-smirnov

I have two vectors with different elements, say `x=c(1,3,4)` , `y= c(2,9)`

I want a vector of ranges that identifies me the elements of vector `x` with 1 and those of `y` with 0, ie

(1,2,3,4,9) -----> (1,0,1,1,0)

How could you get the vector of zeros and ones (1,0,1,1,0)  in r?

Thanks

Comment: This seems to be off topic because it deals mainly with R programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you define a function that do that

```
blah <- function( vector,
                 x=c(1,3,4), 
                 y= c(2,9)){
outVector <- rep(x = NA, times = length(vector))
outVector[vector %in% x] <- 1
outVector[vector %in% y] <- 0
return(outVector)  
}
```

then you can use the function:

```
blah(vector = 1:9)
blah(vector = c(1,2,3,4,9))
```

you can also change the value of x  & y

```
blah(vector = 1:10,x = c(1:5*2), y = c((1:5*2)-1 ))
```

Answer (score 1):

The following option surely isn't numerically optimal, but it's the most simple and direct one:

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4)
b<-c(5,6,7,8)
f<-function(vec0,vec1,inp)
{
  out<-rep(NA,length(inp))       #NA if input elements in neither vector

  for(i in 1:length(inp))
  {                                      #Logical values coerced to 0 and 1 at first, then
    if(sum(inp[i]==vec0))(out[i]<-0);    #summed up and if sum != 0 coerced to logical "TRUE"
  }

  for(i in 1:length(inp))
  {
    if(sum(inp[i]==vec1))(out[i]<-1);
  }

  return (out)
}
```

Works just fine:

```
> f(vec0=a,vec1=b,inp=c(1,6,4,8,2,4,8,7,10))
[1]  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1 NA
```